# Can't ping external websites

Tags: networking, server, proxy

I can't ping google.com with my virtual ubuntu 12.04 server.

I have set up a proxy URL in my /etc/apt/apt.conf file and it says
`Aquire::http::proxy http://urlname.com:9999;`

Now, I don't know a lot about how the proxy works, but I do know when we use it on windows VMachines it's a pac script that we place in internet explorer LAN settings and it automatically detects the script and gives internet access.

I tried including the `9999/proxy.pac` in the apt.conf URL and it didn't seem to work any better.

Would ubuntu know how to handle a proxy.pac assuming it was created for windows? Should my URL include the .pac or just end after the port numbers? I've tried both without sucess, but I would like to know.

A quick test to ping a fellow co-workers' PC was sucessful. So I can see network computers, but not google. or other internet sources.

Comment: Do you want to access the web or do you want to download packages through your proxy? I'm not quite sure  what you're trying to achieve ehre.

Comment: Both actually... but mainly packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware apt doesn't handle PAC files directly. But this file is nothing more than plain text describing the location of your proxy. The Wikipedia page for [Proxy auto-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) has some details. So I would suggest downloading the PAC file to your computer, open it in a text editor and try to find out the correct URL for your proxy. You can enter this information into the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and this should work.

Other software might have seperate ways to handle PAC files. Firefox for instance has network settings. There you can enter the URL to the PAC file.